# OOP - Use a method of one object to process the data of another object from a different class

Tags: python, oop

The program must have two classes and two objects,
belonging to different classes; one object, using a method of its class, must  process the data of another object.

example:

```py
obj1.method(obj2.property)
```

Here is my code :

```py
class first:
    name="first"


class second:
    def change_first(self):
        name="not first"


obj1 = first()
obj2 = second()
    
print(obj1.name)
```

But obj2 is not changing obj1 name.

Comment: Your example program doesn't look like the provided example (from your teacher I'm guessing?). What's different about your program and the example your teacher gave you? What is the `method`? What is the `property`?

Comment: Neither `obj1` nor `obj2` has a `name` field in your code. The *class* `first` has one, and the method `change_first` has a local variable called `name`. Please read up on OOP in Python. From the beginning. You can't learn Python by guess-and-check. It just doesn't work that way. Does your textbook have a chapter on OOP? If not, python.org has an excellent description on all of the basics of Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you mean:

```
class First:
    #use init to run at initialisation
    def __init__(self):
        #use self to assign this variable to the object
        self.name = "first"

class Second:
    def change_name(self):
        obj1.name = "not_first"

obj1 = First()
obj2 = Second()
print(obj1.name)
#change name
obj2.change_name()
print(obj1.name)
```